# How to let users update images based on the images they have already uploaded previously?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

Per the title, for example, a user uploaded some photos in specific order previously using filePond, then the server stored the photos in Cloudinary and store the URL into the database.

Now I want filePond to enable that user to update the photos, including adding new photos, deleting old photos, reorder the photos, how can I achieve that in React?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no need to provide code, because I don't have code that is relevant to the function I am asking for.